# UVs won't 'stick' -- newbie help

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm very new to 3d modeling in general. I tried to make a simple 'magical girl' staff to start. When I unwrap it, the uvs are pretty close together and small, so I rearranged them all to my liking. I'm not sure how to like...get the new uv layout to 'stick'. If I deselect everything and then unwrap it again, it just goes back to the old, default, cluttered UV.

I feel like there's something I should be clicking or something so this won't happen! It's probably right in front of me and I don't even see it, haha.

[image]

Here is the UV layout I would like (the one I manually arranged):
[image]

Here is the default it keeps reverting to: 
[image]

Any help would be really great! thank you so much, guys. I'm hoping I'll get good at this one day :)

Comment: OH here's the actual staff thing I made! Sorry if the topology is like, really bad. Still figuring this all out! http://imgur.com/0G0AWWv

Answer (score 3):

You can pin UV vertices with <kbd>P</kbd> and unpin with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>. This will prevent them from being effected by unwrapping.

Pinned UV vertices will turn red.

Answer (score 0):

When you edit the UV map to be how you want, just leave it—it's already unwrapped. If you tell Blender to unwrap it again, it'll do it from scratch.